# Power BI integration in MVC application

Tags: c#-4.0

How to integrate powreBI tool into MVC application.

I have been trying to integrate last one week but not getting steps.
How to integrate powreBI tool into MVC application.

I have been trying to integrate last one week but not getting steps.
How to integrate powreBI tool into MVC application.

I have been trying to integrate last one week but not getting steps.
How to integrate powreBI tool into MVC application.

I have been trying to integrate last one week but not getting steps.
How to integrate powreBI tool into MVC application.

I have been trying to integrate last one week but not getting steps.
How to integrate powreBI tool into MVC application.

I have been trying to integrate last one week but not getting steps.
How to integrate powreBI tool into MVC application.

I have been trying to integrate last one week but not getting steps.
How to integrate powreBI tool into MVC application.

I have been trying to integrate last one week but not getting steps.